# Material-ui Stepper height not adjusted properly

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

The new Stepper component is awesome, except that the height of each step won't adjust properly when its child components change from hidden to visible, or vice versa via CSS. Specifically, if a component's style changes from `display: 'none'` to `display: 'inline'`, the height of content will remain the same. As a result, the newly visible component won't show properly.

However, if the component is dynamically created (as opposed to be made visible with CSS), the height would adjust properly. Unfortunately in my case, I do need the component to be there even when they're not visible.

Has anyone encountered similar problem? I'm using react.js v0.14 and material-ui v0.15.0-beta.1.